# How do I export my biom object to a file in biom format?

Tags: python

I'm using the python API for the biom-format package. I read in two files in biom format and merged them, like so:

```
In [1]: import biom

In [2]: a = biom.load_table('./table-a.biom')

In [3]: b = biom.load_table('./table-b.biom')

In [4]: a
Out[4]: 51116 x 46 <class 'biom.table.Table'> with 185077 nonzero entries (7% dense)

In [5]: b
Out[5]: 37479 x 26 <class 'biom.table.Table'> with 100124 nonzero entries (10% dense)

In [6]: c = a.merge(b)

In [7]: c
Out[7]: 67022 x 47 <class 'biom.table.Table'> with 254555 nonzero entries (8% dense)
```

How do I now export this biom object (`c`) as a biom file? There are a few methods available, eg, `.to_tsv()`, but I don't see a way to save this object in biom format.

Comment: Are you using the [biomformat](https://bioconductor.org/packages/biomformat/) package of bioconductor through Python? Or the biom-format package? Anyway in R the relevant function is write_biom so it might be the same in the python package

Answer (score 4):

You can use the functions `to_hdf5` and `to_json` from the [biom-format package](http://biom-format.org/documentation/generated/biom.table.Table.html):

`to_hdf5`

```
with biom.util.biom_open('output.biom', 'w') as f:
    merged_table.to_hdf5(f, "example")
```

`to_json`

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(merged_table.to_json("example"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in [PiCRUST](http://picrust.github.io/) you can use

```
from picrust.util import write_biom_table

write_biom_table(c,'table-c.biom')
```

Note, however, that depending if you want json or hdf5 format and if your metadata are complex, you may need to use additional arguments. These are the arguments of the function:

```
def write_biom_table(biom_table, biom_table_fp, compress=True,
                 write_hdf5=HAVE_H5PY, format_fs=None):
"""Writes a BIOM table to the specified filepath

Parameters
----------
biom_table : biom.Table
    The table object to write out
biom_table_fp : str
    The path to the output file
compress : bool, optional
    Defaults to ``True``. If True, built-in compression on the output HDF5
    file will be enabled. This option is only relevant if ``write_hdf5`` is
    ``True``.
write_hdf5 : bool, optional
    Defaults to ``True`` if H5PY is installed and to ``False`` if H5PY is
    not installed. If ``True`` the output biom table will be written as an
    HDF5 binary file, otherwise it will be a JSON string.
format_fs : dict, optional
    Formatting functions to be passed to `Table.to_hdf5`

Notes
-----
This code was adapted from QIIME 1.9
"""
```

I have some problems to perform a simple operation and write the output of biom data generated with picrust, it might be helpful as an [example](https://github.com/biocore/qiime/issues/2205) of how to use the arguments.